# Converting a pyspark dataframe to a nested json object

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame as follows

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| item_id |   popular_tags   | popularity_score
____________________________________________________________________________
| id_1        Samsung         0.4
| id_1        long battery    0.8
| id_2        Apple           0.9
| id_2        UI              0.9
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

I want to group this data frame by `item_id` and output as a file with each line being a `json` object

```
{id_1: {"Samsung":{"popularity_score":0.4}, "long_battery":{"popularity_score": 0.8}}}
{id_2: {"Apple": {"popularity_score": 0.9},"UI":{"popularity_score":0.9}}}
```

I tried using `to_json` and `collect_list` functions but I get a list not a nested json object.
This is a big distributed dataframe, so converting to pandas or collecting it into a single machine is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create some map types for your JSON:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('item_id').agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(
            F.struct('popular_tags', F.struct('popularity_score'))
        )
    ).alias('m')
).select(
    F.to_json(
        F.create_map('item_id', 'm')
    ).alias('col')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"id_2":{"Apple":{"popularity_score":0.9},"UI":{"popularity_score":0.9}}}            |
|{"id_1":{"Samsung":{"popularity_score":0.4},"long battery":{"popularity_score":0.8}}}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Without `map_from_entries`, you might have to rely on some dirty hacks:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('item_id').agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.create_map('popular_tags', F.struct('popularity_score'))
    ).alias('m')
).select(
    F.regexp_replace(
        F.regexp_replace(
            F.to_json(F.create_map('item_id', 'm')),
            '(\\[|\\])', 
            ''
        ),
    '\\},\\{', 
    ','
    ).alias('col')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"id_2":{"Apple":{"popularity_score":0.9},"UI":{"popularity_score":0.9}}}            |
|{"id_1":{"Samsung":{"popularity_score":0.4},"long battery":{"popularity_score":0.8}}}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I kind of get what you are doing . Thanks but I am using spark 2.2 which does not have this map_from_entries function. 

Can i achieve that functionality using the spark2.2 functions ?

Comment: @NG_21 ... that's a bit difficult. I added a hacky way to do that, not sure if it works for you.

Comment: I just figured out a way combining the solution you mentioned with a UDF based approach which works on spark 2.2. Although would prefer spark functions over UDF for performance . Thanks for the help